# case_when using variable name to change data value

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(var1_lag0 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
                 , var1_lag1 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
                 , var2_lag0 = c(34,5,45,7,2,1)
                 , var2_lag2 = c(0,0,34,5,45,7)
                 )
```

I want to change a specific value of each columns using the following logic:

- Variable name contains "_lag1" then the **first** element of the column has to turn into NA
- Variable name contains "_lag2" then the **first and second** element of the column has to turn into NA
- Else the column remains as it is

The expected result should be look like:

```
df_new <- data.frame(var1_lag0 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
                 , var1_lag1 = c(NA,1,2,3,4,5)
                 , var2_lag0 = c(34,5,45,7,2,1)
                 , var2_lag2 = c(NA,NA,34,5,45,7)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution might look like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(var1_lag0 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
, var1_lag1 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
, var2_lag0 = c(34,5,45,7,2,1)
, var2_lag2 = c(0,0,34,5,45,7)
)

df_new <- df

df_new[1 , grep(pattern="_lag1", colnames(df))] <- NA
df_new[c(1,2) , grep(pattern="_lag2", colnames(df))] <- NA
df_new
#>   var1_lag0 var1_lag1 var2_lag0 var2_lag2
#> 1         1        NA        34        NA
#> 2         2         1         5        NA
#> 3         3         2        45        34
#> 4         4         3         7         5
#> 5         5         4         2        45
#> 6         6         5         1         7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As you have the original unlagged variables in your df you could simply recompute the lagged values using e.g. `dplyr::lag` which by default will give you `NA`s:

```r
df <- data.frame(var1_lag0 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
                 , var1_lag1 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
                 , var2_lag0 = c(34,5,45,7,2,1)
                 , var2_lag2 = c(0,0,34,5,45,7)
)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(var1_lag1 = dplyr::lag(var1_lag0, n = 1), var2_lag2 = dplyr::lag(var2_lag0, n = 2))
#>   var1_lag0 var1_lag1 var2_lag0 var2_lag2
#> 1         1        NA        34        NA
#> 2         2         1         5        NA
#> 3         3         2        45        34
#> 4         4         3         7         5
#> 5         5         4         2        45
#> 6         6         5         1         7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Unfortunately I can’t do that as there are other operations involved that pushed me to replace the original NA into 0, but now I need to restore the original NA and the only way to do it is by reading the column title

Comment: Okay. I See. I already guessed that you probably have a good reason to ask for  a `case_when` approach. Best S.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a for loop that checks the column names of the df for the key words "_lag1" and "_lag2" and turns the corresponding values to NA.

```
for (i in 1:length(df)){
  if (grepl("_lag1",colnames(df)[i])){
    df[1,i] = NA
    }
  else if (grepl("_lag2",colnames(df)[i])){
    df[1:2,i] = NA
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wrap a `case_when` inside a helper function and use `mutate_at` with `contains` to get the proper columns.

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(contains("lag1")),
           function(x, lag) fix(x, "lag1")) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(contains("lag2")),
           function(x, lag) fix(x, "lag2"))
```

Which produces

```
  var1_lag0 var1_lag1 var2_lag0 var2_lag2
1         1        NA        34        NA
2         2         1         5        NA
3         3         2        45        34
4         4         3         7         5
5         5         4         2        45
6         6         5         1         7
```

Here is the helper function called `fix`

```
fix <- function(x, lag){
  real_lag <- case_when(stringr::str_detect("lag1", lag) ~ 1,
            stringr::str_detect("lag2", lag) ~ 2)
  
  x[1:real_lag] <- NA
  return(x)
}
```